# Storing HttpClient BaseAddress on web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I want to store the HttpClient BaseAddress Uri on my ASP.NET MVC4 project web.config.

In which section is the correct place to add this configuration?

Comment: Make sure to note this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23438416/1828879

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in web.config

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BaseAddress" value="http://xxx/"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Get value like this:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseAddress"]
```